# SMLNJ expand # in output

Tags: smlnj

I have the following:

```
val it = DATAX ("hello",DATAX ("world",DATAX #,DATAX #),...
```

Is there a way to make the SMLNJ interpreter expand "#" so that I can see what the exact data is? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found an answer:

> http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~me/212/environment.html
>
> When SML/NJ prints a data structure,
>   it prints that data structure only to
>   a certain depth. Beneath that depth it
>   prints a # instead. This is generally
>   a good thing, since data structures
>   can be very large (and even cyclic).
>   However, the default depth to which
>   SML/NJ prints data structures is 5,
>   which is usually not enough. You can
>   adjust the depth to which it prints
>   data structures by entering, for
>   example,
>
> - `Control.Print.printDepth := 10;`
>
> to set the depth to 10. SML/NJ also
>   abbreviates lists and strings over a
>   certain length. You can set the length
>   at which this happens by setting
>   Control.Print.printLength and
>   Control.Print.stringDepth, in a manner
>   analogous to the above.