# ML - Error in printing value (#)

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I wrote function, and for example I have the next line (this is only a part from the function):

```
up (St(d)::Dt::St(c)::[rp]) = Pr (Sym(d), Sym(c))
```

`Pr`, `Sym`, `St`, `Dt` - are all datatypes; `d` and `c` are strings.

When I run the function `up`, on arguments `([St("hello"),Dt,St("hi"),rp]),` it's print `val it =Pr(Sym(#), Sym(#))`, instead of `val it = Pr(Sym("hello"), Sym("hi"))`. Why? Thanks.

Comment: The answer:  Can use in this command: `Control.Print.printDepth:=100`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMLNJ expand # in output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756460/smlnj-expand-in-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsmlnj%5D%20Control.Print.printDepth&submit=search) multiple times already. The solution is as Adam Sh describes.
The same goes for lists and strings, just set the `Control.Print.printLength`.